# Stop animation on click with separate function

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a div with multiple images in them that we are animating based on a click of another image. It has two options to click on like the code below

```
$('.AspenL').click( function() { 
    $('.route-box').fadeOut('slow');
    $('.AspenR').fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.AspenR .walking-icon').click( function() { 
    $(".AspenDiv img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).delay(9000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('.AspenR').delay(100).fadeOut('slow');
});
$('.AspenR .handicap-icon').click( function() { 
    $(".Aspen-elvDiv img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(1000*index).fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
    $('.AspenR').delay(100).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

How can I make it so if you click on one it stops the others animation. Currently if you are fast enough you can click on both images and it starts both animation queues when it should only show either `.AspenR .walking-icon` or `.AspenR .handicap-icon animation.`

Comment: See this function : http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Have you tried finish? http://api.jquery.com/finish/

Comment: Yeah i tried adding stop after the $(this) but did not stop them and still did both if you click fast enough.

Comment: i also tried adding stop after $('.AspenR .handicap-icon') and $('.AspenR .walking-icon') but no luck either

Comment: Set up a demo at http://jsfiddle.net and you'll get more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.  Supply clearQueue and jumpToEnd arguments as true to finish current animations if that's your intent.

Comment: i also tried adding stop after $('.AspenR .handicap-icon') and $('.AspenR .walking-icon') but no luck either